# Be notified when an Activity's size is going to change, and when it has changed

Tags: android

Can I be notified of the following events for an Activity:

- screenSizeWillChange
- screenSizeDidChange

I realize that I can probably override the main View's `onSizeChanged()` and be notified when the View has changed, but how can I be notified when it's about to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what you are looking for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: Ok, so the only way to be notified of something like that is to tell Android that you want to handle it yourself?